# Error when using XML API findall() in with python 2.6

Tags: python, xml, alexa-internet

I'm using this code below to retrieve information from the Alexa API, this code works well on Python 2.7 but I have to use Python 2.6 and it gives me an error:

> findall() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)

I presume that this method has change in Python 2.7 but I don't know how to make it work in 2.6.

```
NS_PREFIXES = {
    "alexa": "http://alexa.amazonaws.com/doc/2005-10-05/",
    "awis": "http://awis.amazonaws.com/doc/2005-07-11",
}

tree = api.sites_linking_in(domain + ".eu", count=10, start=0)
alexa_sites_linkin_in = {}
for element in tree.findall('//awis:SitesLinkingIn/awis:Site',NS_PREFIXES):
    alexa_sites_linkin_in.update({
    element.find('awis:Title', NS_PREFIXES).text: element.find('awis:Url', "awis").text})
```

Comment: Are you using the ``findall`` function of xml.etree.ElementTree as in [this documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.findall) ? I'm not sure how this can even work in Python 2.7 provided the doc only mentions 1 argument (not counting self).

Comment: It tries to imports xml.etree.cElementTree and if it fails it imports xml.etree.ElementTree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The api used `lxml`(ElementTree as backport) for parsing xml. The `lxml` **allowed** additional argument - namespace, but ElementTree does not allow. That is problem.
So as hotfix I recommend install lxml.

Answer (score 1):

With Python 2.6 (and earlier) you need to register the namespace manually and resolve it into the Clark notation before for `find()` is able to recognize them.

First, register the namespace as describe at http://effbot.org/zone/element-namespaces.htm:

```
from xml import ElementTree
try:
    register_namespace = ElementTree.register_namespace
except AttributeError:
    def register_namespace(prefix, uri):
        ElementTree._namespace_map[uri] = prefix

for short_name, url in NS_PREFIXES.items():
    register_namespace(short_name, url)
```

Next you need to resolve the namespaced XPaths yourself into the Clark notation, which `find()` uses internally. For example, `awis:Title` resolves to `{http://awis.amazonaws.com/doc/2005-07-11}Title`:

```
def resolved_xpath(xpath, namespace):
    result = xpath
    for short_name, url in namespace.items():
        result = re.sub(r'\b' + short_name + ':', '{' + url + '}', result)
    return result
```

Now it is easy to write a modified `find()` and `findall()` that honors namespaces even with Python 2.6:

```
def find_with_namespace(element, xpath, namespace):
    return element.find(resolved_xpath(xpath, namespace))

def findall_with_namespace(element, xpath, namespace):
    return element.findall(resolved_xpath(xpath, namespace))
```

Your example can be implemented as:

```
NS_PREFIXES = {
    "alexa": "http://alexa.amazonaws.com/doc/2005-10-05/",
    "awis": "http://awis.amazonaws.com/doc/2005-07-11",
}

tree = api.sites_linking_in(domain + ".eu", count=10, start=0)
alexa_sites_linkin_in = {}
for element in findall_with_namespace(tree, '//awis:SitesLinkingIn/awis:Site',NS_PREFIXES):
    title = find_with_namespace(element, 'awis:Title', NS_PREFIXES).text
    url = find_with_namespace(element, 'awis:Url', NS_PREFIXES).text
    alexa_sites_linkin_in[title] = url
```

So, yes, if possible, use `lxml`.